# Sqlite database locking with (WAL) write-ahead logging enabled

Tags: android, sqlite

My sqlite database is running into locks even though I have `WAL` enabled and I'm using a singleton instance of my DbHelper across the entire app, which is as follows:

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { 

  private static final String mTAG = "DB_HELPER";
  private static DatabaseHelper sInstance;

  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database_name";
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

  public static synchronized DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {

    if (sInstance == null) {
      sInstance = new DatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return sInstance;
  }

  private DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }
}
```

For inserts, I have the following function:

```
public void insertToDb(String tableName, ContentValues contentValues) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    sqLiteDatabase.enableWriteAheadLogging();
    sqLiteDatabase.beginTransactionNonExclusive();

    sqLiteDatabase.insert(tableName, null, contentValues);
    sqLiteDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful();
    sqLiteDatabase.endTransaction();
    sqLiteDatabase.close();
}
```

Any idea why this might be happening?

**Update:**
I have an asynctask from where the problem stems by throwing out an `attempt to re-open an already-closed object` exception. Following that, I start getting the error below in my logcat:

```
#################################################################
Error Code : 5 (SQLITE_BUSY)
Caused By : The database file is locked.
(database is locked (code 5))
#################################################################
' Stack Trace: 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5)
#################################################################
Error Code : 5 (SQLITE_BUSY)
Caused By : The database file is locked.
(database is locked (code 5))
#################################################################
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecute(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.execute(SQLiteConnection.java:679)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.beginTransactionUnchecked(SQLiteSession.java:319)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.beginTransaction(SQLiteSession.java:298)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:510)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.beginTransactionNonExclusive(SQLiteDatabase.java:445)
at com.ontheway.otw.entermarkets.helpers.database.OTWUserDb.updateOTWUserLocation(OTWUserDb.java:124)
at com.ontheway.otw.entermarkets.services.FusedLocationService.onLocationChanged(FusedLocationService.java:146)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzart$zzb$1.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzart$zzb$1.zzs(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaaz.zzb(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaaz$zza.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
'
```

Comment: Where exactly does it fail? What is the error message?

Comment: I've added error details above.

Comment: What makes you think that you can use a single database object from multple threads?

Comment: That's the whole purpose of the singleton, isn't it? Or each thread and background service is starting its own instance?

Comment: Are you asking what you are doing or what you should doing?

Comment: Purpose of my question is to know how to avoid locks in the database. I had set up the singleton based on the following article: http://touchlabblog.tumblr.com/post/24474750219/single-sqlite-connection but that didn't seem to address multiple threading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SQLiteDatabase` (wrapped by the `SQLiteOpenHelper`) is threadsafe (it uses a `SQLiteConnectionPool` and a  `SQLiteSession`for each thread) but you should **not close** it until you are completely done with the database, which for most application is never. This is basically what the linked article says.

On the other hand you should make sure that transactions are always ended, even when not successful, e.g. :

```
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
sqLiteDatabase.enableWriteAheadLogging();
sqLiteDatabase.beginTransactionNonExclusive();
try {
    sqLiteDatabase.insert(tableName, null, contentValues);
    sqLiteDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
    sqLiteDatabase.endTransaction();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One DB connection object equals one transaction, so multiple threads must use multiple DB connections.

Alternatively, you could ensure that no two threads access the database at the same time. But then it is not enough to put `synchronized` on `getInstance()`; you'd have to lock all database code (e.g., the entire `insertToDb()` function) with a shared lock.